# How to register helper function in lightncandy handlebar

Tags: php, handlebars.js

I am facing problem with lighncandy handlebar. I need to create a helper function and need to render it while its called. I dont understand how to register a helper function in this handlebar. Please some one help me.

```
$handle = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/Cubet/lightncandy-master/src/lightncandy.php';
require_once($handle);
$template = "{{{helper1}}}";
$phpStr = LightnCandy::compile($template);
$renderer = LightnCandy::prepare($phpStr);
echo $renderer(Array('helpers' => Array('helper1' => helper_optionsprice));
```

This is my code which is not working. The link to the handlebar library is given below.

[LightnCandy](https://github.com/zordius/lightncandy)

Please Help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register helper function when compile() , not when render().

```
$template = "{{{helper1}}}";
$phpStr = LightnCandy::compile($template, Array(
    'helpers' => Array('helper1' => helper_optionsprice
));
$renderer = LightnCandy::prepare($phpStr);

echo $renderer(Array('foo' => 'bar'));
```